# making a JSON file from img lib

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

Iam trying to make a .JSON file i can use in my angularjs project. I want the backend to auto update the site to what is in the img folder.

what ive done is:

first i search for all the items in the folder:

```
    public static String[] GetFilesFrom(String searchFolder, String[] filters, bool isRecursive)
    {
        List<String> filesFound = new List<String>();
        var searchOption = isRecursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
        foreach (var filter in filters)
          {
            filesFound.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, String.Format("*.{0}", filter), searchOption));
          }
        return filesFound.ToArray();
    }
```

save it to an array:

```
String searchFolder = @"images\galleri";
var filters = new String[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp" };
files = GetFilesFrom(searchFolder, filters, false);
```

trying to write it to a JSON

```
       var _data = new Dictionary<string, string> {};

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            _data = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
                { "img", files[i] }
         };
        }
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data.ToArray());
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"\js\json.json", json);
```

this gives me the output of :

```
[
  {
    "Key":"img",
    "Value":"images\\galleri\\placeholder.png"
  }
]
```

The array "files" does contain more than 1 picture, all the path in "files" are correct. Why does it only display the last item in the array? I know the "for" statement is wrong, how do i add to a dictionary without writing over the previus saved with the same key and
how do i get it to display it all in JSON format as:

```
[
 {
   "img": "images\\galleri\\placeholder.png"
 },
 {
   "img": "images\\galleri\\img1.png"
 },
 {
   "img": "images\\galleri\\img2.png"
 }
]
```

Comment: I think you are overwriting _data while iterating in the loop, that's why you only have the last entry.

Comment: youre right, but i have no idea how not to overwrite the data in the dic, when the all have the same "img" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class Image which you will be serialize

```
public class Image
{
   [JsonProperty("img")]
   public string ImagePath {get; set;}
}
```

And your for loop will looks like this:

```
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
   Image img = new Image() {ImagePath = files[i]};
   images.Add(img);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(images);
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments I came to understand the problem is not just Serialization, The first issue is to enter the Same Key everytime. So I came up with `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead of `new Dictionary<string, string>`. Now it looks like this

```
string[] files = { "placeholder.png", "img1.png", "img2.png" }; //Just Entered Dummy Data for test
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    _data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("img", files[i]));
}
JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jss.Converters.Add(new KeyValuePairJsonConverter());
jss.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
jss.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data, jss);
```

We also need the `KeyValuePairJsonConverter` to be like this

```
public class KeyValuePairJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = value as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key.ToString());
            writer.WriteValue(item.Value.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var target = Create(objectType, jsonObject);
        serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }

    private object Create(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject)
    {
        if(FieldExists("Key", jsonObject))
        {
            return jsonObject["Key"].ToString();
        }

        if(FieldExists("Value", jsonObject))
        {
            return jsonObject["Value"].ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jsonObject)
    {
        return jsonObject[fieldName] != null;
    }
}
```

and the output will be

[image: Screenshot of JSON]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering the qustion, with this very elaborate answer :-)